# Scheme function that see is the ends match

Tags: lisp, scheme

So here i have a couple of defined list that i would like to use:

```
(DEFINE list0 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j) )
(DEFINE list1 (LIST 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g) )
(DEFINE list2 (LIST 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z) )
(DEFINE list3 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'l 'k 'j) )
(DEFINE list4 (LIST 'n 'o 'p 'q 'q 'p 'o 'n) )
(DEFINE list5 '( (a b) c (d e d) c (a b) ) )
(DEFINE list6 '( (h i) (j k) l (m n) ) )
(DEFINE list7 (f (a b) c (d e d) (b a) f) )
```

what i would like to do is create a recursive function for a 'endsmatch' function that would do as such:

ENDSMATCH:
`(endsmatch 1st)` which should return `#t` if the first element in the list is the same as the last element in the list, and return
`#f` otherwise. That is,

`(endsmatch '(s t u v w x y z) )`
would/should return:
`#f`

```
(endsmatch (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j)
```

would/should return:
    `#t`

and

Both `(endsmatch '())` and `(endsmatch '(a))`
should return `#t`, etc.

Also is the function can read complex lists such as:
    `(endsmatch '((a b) c (d e d) c (a b)) )`
which would then return:
    `#t`
and:

```
(endsmatch '((a b) c (d e d) c (b a)) )

(endsmatch '((y z) y) )
```

should both return `#f`

How might this function be coded because i am new to scheme and would see what it may look like, Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's as simple as it gets:

```
(define (endsmatch lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #t
      (equal? (first lst) (last lst))))
```

If your Scheme interpreter doesn't include the procedures `first` and `last`, they're very simple to implement:

```
(define (first lst)
  (car lst))

(define (last lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
        (else (last (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: Thank you i am going to try this out.

Comment: Doesn't work on the empty list

Comment: would it be the same if one were to replace the `lst` with `lis` instead

Comment: @user1786512 it doesn't matter what name you use, as long as it's not a name already in use. For example, it'd be a bad idea to call it `list`, because that's a built-in procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this solution, but it fails for the 2 last tests you describe:

```
(define (endsmatch lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (first '()) (last '()))
    (cond
      ((null? lst)         (eq? first last))
      ((pair? (car lst))   (loop (car lst) first last)
                           (loop (cdr lst) first last))
      ((null? first)       (loop (cdr lst) (car lst) (car lst)))
      (else                (loop (cdr lst) first (car lst))))))


; racket test code
(require rackunit)
(check-eq? (endsmatch '(s t u v w x y z)) #f)
(check-eq? (endsmatch (list 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j)) #t)
(check-eq? (endsmatch '()) #t)
(check-eq? (endsmatch '(a)) #t)
(check-eq? (endsmatch '((a b) c (d e d) c (b a))) #t)
; these fail
(check-eq? (endsmatch '((a b) c (d e d) c (b a))) #f)
(check-eq? (endsmatch '((y z) y)) #f)
```

and indeed you say both

```
"(endsmatch '((a b) c (d e d) c (b a)) ) which would then return: #t"
```

and

```
"(endsmatch '((a b) c (d e d) c (b a)) ) should return #f"
```

which is contradictory.

Comment: Sorry i accidentally created a typo, I corrected it if you want to recheck it and see what i actually mean.